# how to solve "the return value is not 0" when downloading R package "HPO.db"

Tags: r, download, package, bioconductor

when I tried to library("clusterProfiler")
an error said:
package or namespace load failed for ‘clusterProfiler’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
There is no package with the name 'HPO.db'(translated from Chinese,may not be the same as the English version)
so I tired to download the package"HPO.db"
then I got a warning:
In install.packages(...): the return value of installing "HPO.db" is not 0

I have tried to change the Cran version,change the download method and many other measures searched from Internet which I didn't actually understand why,and they all failed.
What could I do now?
Am I suppose to change my R version from 4.3.2 to 4.0.4?

Answer (score 1):

This package isn't on CRAN (since a long time). It is on Bioconductor. Follow the [installation instructions](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release//data/annotation/html/HPO.db.html):

```
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("HPO.db")
```

Comment: i did download it with the same codes you post,however it didn‘t work.What's worse,after i tried some other methods to fix it,my rstudio broke and i have to redownload it :( Anyway thank you a lot